Obtaining URL of page with basic authentication in Firefox
I have a page which requires Basic Authentication - for example https://authenticationtest.com/HTTPAuth/. What I want is to obtain the URL of this page before the users enter their credentials.
In Chrome I am able to do this via both the extension (chrome.tabs.query -> tabs[0].url) and via pure javascript (window.location). In Firefox however both information displays "about:newtab".
Is there something I'm missing when it comes to pages with Basic Authentication in firefox?
I've tried to search the web for a related problem but I couldn't find any.
I'm expecting to obtain the URL (in the example given authenticationtest.com/HTTPAuth) in some way just like in the case of Chrome.

"obtain the URL" — from where? What would be the context of the code you want to run to get the URL?

@Pointy From either a javascript or Firefox extension code.

Try to use the tabs.onUpdate event.

@Titus Thanks for the advice, unfortunatelly it didn't work. There is only one change event when I jump onto the page (status: "loading"), and the url and title are "about:newtab" and "New Tab" respectively.

I see, in that case, it seems that Firefox doesn't update the tabs URL before the user authentication is completed. Another thing you could try is to use the webRequest API. I think you can still use this API on Firefox MV3 extensions but I'm sure that you cannot use it in Chrome MV3 extension.

@Titus Thank you for the fast reply. Using the onAuthRequired method of the webRequest API I was able to obtain the required URL. I think with some adjustments this can be used in both Chrome and Firefox extensions as well.

I think the answer provided by @Titus solves the problem. The information contained in the onAuthRequired method of the webRequest API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) does shoe the correct URL of the page.
